# Are questions regarding Art History on-topic?

Tags: discussion

This includes general questions about art history, but also "specialized" ones. Examples: 
"Does painter X belong to the style of Cubism or Purism?"
"How do Cubism and Purism differ?"
"What is architect's Y contribution to Cubism"

Comment: Isn't the style and school of a painter something which requires technical knowledge of Art itself rather than history? Unless it involves history in some way, I would say it's off-topic to ask which style does the artist follow or how do different styles differ. Contributions of a specific artist to a style is however something that can be looked up as its history

Comment: You raise a valid point, however, that particular technical knowledge of Art is usually considered to be the subject of art history. Consider that not all people that can differentiate Cubism and Purism are artists.

Comment: I could imagine such questions going on a potential Fine Arts.SE, but not on the existing Arts & Crafts.SE.